# PyQGIS plugin, disable Qt dial at start, from outside __init__ function?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I know I can disable the dial widget from the main function that loads the Qt dialog form with `self.dial_name.setEnabled(False)` but don't want to modify the function, to keep all modifications separated.

What is the best way, I don't see options to do it from the .ui file itself, so maybe there is some 'onload' event for the widgets, something like:

```
def on_dial_name_loaded(self):
    self.dial_name.setEnabled(False)
```

Or a trick to replace the `self` by `qgis.something`.dial_name.setEnabled(False) outside a function?

Comment: What main function?

Comment: The main function is the _ _init_ _ function of the class that builds the Qt form for the plugin, Instead of disabling the dial from there I'd prefer to keep my own code separate, mainly for maintenance. Sorry for the 'qml' in the OP, I removed it...